# java.lang.NullPointerException en JasperPrint con JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

¡Hola!

Tengo un documento/reporte de tipo Jasper que deseo acceder y posteriormente imprimir.

Para ello ingreso el siguiente código:

```
//Creo la variable que contendrá el reporte
    JasperReport miReporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("src/REPORTE/MotivosDebitos.jasper");

    //Creo mi lista con los parametros a enviar
    Map misParametros = new HashMap();

    //Ingreso los parametros necesarios
    misParametros.put("parametro1", parametro1);
    misParametros.put("parametro2", parametro2);
    misParametros.put("parametro3", parametro3);
    misParametros.put("parametro4", parametro4);

    //Establezco la conexion
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/SisForPres","postgres","postgres");

    //Preparo para mostrar
    JasperPrint miJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(miReporte, misParametros, conn);

    JasperViewer miJasperViewer = new JasperViewer(miJasperPrint, false);

    //Le doy un titulo al documento
    miJasperViewer.setTitle("UnTitulo");

    //Lo hago visible
    miJasperViewer.setVisible(true);

    //Cierro la conexion
    conn.close();
```

Bien, ahora el problema es el siguiente: cuando ejecuto el codigo y se llama a este método me lanza la siguiente exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:326)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
```

Más específicamente en la siguiente línea:

```
//Preparo para mostrar
    JasperPrint miJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(miReporte, misParametros, conn);
```

Utilizo iReport v5.5.0.

¿Alguien me daría un mano por aqui?

Comment: probaste si alguno de esas tres variables , trae un valor null?, trata de hacer `System.out.println(variable);` en cada una de ellas

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Pero siento decirte que ninguno de ellos se encuentran en valor null. He comprobado sus valores tanto por salida por pantalla como por debuggin.

Comment: Checa esto, puede ser que te sirva: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/520803/getting-null-pointer-exception-fillreport o esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815094/nullpointerexception-while-creating-jasper-report

Comment: Ya habia visto ese post, pero realmente no los entiendo. No entiendo ingles y aunque pongo en un traductor tampoco entiendo la solución que proponen. Además, no es como esta página donde se valorizan las respuestas, por ende no sé a quien hacerle caso realmente.

Comment: Ramiro `iReport` dejó de mantenerse hace ya casi 3 años, puedes verlo en la nota (en amarillo) [en este enlace](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer). Se recomienda que actualices todo: bibliotecas que serán usadas en tu proyecto y el programa de diseño de reportes, a [`JasperSoftStudio`](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) y que desestimes **totalmente** `iReport`. Esa será la forma de resolver el problema de raíz.

Comment: Lo que dice la nota es esto, dado que dices tener problemas con el inglés: ***Anuncio de soporte de iReport / Jaspersoft Studio**
A partir de la versión 5.5.0, Jaspersoft Studio será el cliente oficial de diseño de JasperReports. iReport seguirá siendo un producto admitido **en modo de solo mantenimiento hasta el 31 de diciembre de 2015**, lo que significa que continuaremos reparando defectos críticos en próximas versiones, pero no se agregarán nuevas características al cliente de iReport. ¡Continúe manteniendo sus informes existentes **con el nuevo Jaspersoft Studio**!*

Comment: Muchas gracias A.Cedano, y un verdadero aprecio por el tiempo de incluso traducir del inglés al español.

Comment: De nada Ramiro, ese tipo de errores en Jasper son debidos a **problemas de compatibilidad entre bibliotecas**. Además siempre me ha parecido una confusión eso de las bibliotecas para reportes... entre `iText`, `Jasper`, `iReport` ... Me parece que con `JasperSoftStudio` unificaron y clarificaron un poco más eso... lo cierto es que como te quede en el proyecto alguno de los `.jar` de bibliotecas antiguas, o varios `.jar` de versiones distintas, vas a tener errores parecidos a este. Si usas `Maven` sería mejor que borres los `.jar` agregados *a mano* y que agregues las dependencias vía Maven.